# Reading google home page using ruby: Connection attempt failed

Tags: ruby

I'm attempting to make a very basic ruby script, to pull down the contents of a webpage as a string. Once I can pull down the page as a string, I'm sure the rest will be a matter of trial and error.

When I had trouble with the page I originally wanted to use (a https, redirected URL), I plugged in google instead, and stripped things back to nothing, and still I'm getting an error.

Here's the code:

```
require 'open-uri'
file = open('www.google.com')
contents = file.read
puts contents
```

and the error message I get is:

```
http.rb:763: in 'initialize': A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host failed to respond - connect(2) (Errno::ETIMEDOUT)
```

I've also tried:

```
https://www.google.com
```

and

```
http://www.google.com
```

with the same result.

Does anyone have any idea what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should use `http://www.google.com`. Are you behind a proxy? What version of Ruby? It works fine for me as-is once you use the correct URI.

Comment: Can you do `ping google.com` from your shell (not within irb/ruby)?

Comment: @DaveNewton you should post an answer rather than a comment since it is in fact an answer. :D

Comment: @DaveNewton Hi thanks, as I said in my question, I tried prepending both http:// and https:// which gave me the exact same error message :(

Comment: I get a `Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen` when trying to `open('www.google.com')` without `http://`

Comment: @iamnotmaynard I try "ping google.com" and get "Request timed out." 4 times. Is this a network issue then?

Comment: Yes, it is; that's why I asked if you're behind a proxy. I know you tried both `http://` and `https://`, I told you which one you were *supposed* to use.

Comment: It sounds like it. Possibly a DNS problem, or a proxy/firewall issue as suggested by @DaveNewton. (I was about to ask if you can connect to any other URIs, but... obviously...) You also might want to check your hosts file (/etc/hosts on linux; I don't remember how to find it on Windows) and see if there is an entry for google. There should not be one, so if there is, delete it, and maybe do a virus scan. Other than that, I can't think of why google.com would be timing out.

Comment: @Paul What version of ruby or you using? I can't see the issue on my local machine.

Comment: @Sylar I'm using 1.9.3

Comment: @Paul do this in terminal for us and post exact results: which ruby and ruby -v

Comment: @Sylar, that's what I did "1.9.3p448 <2013-06-27> [i386-mingw32]"

Comment: @Paul How about typing, in terminal: which ruby

Comment: @Sylar The result of "ruby -v" is "1.9.3p448 <2013-06-27> [i386-mingw32]". "which" is not a command.

Comment: @Paul Are you on a Mac or Windows?

Comment: Knew it! Update your title to let others know you are on Windows. I'll load up vmware and see.

Comment: @Paul I have tried it on my Win 7 machine and it worked using     http://www.google.com. I think you have a connection issue to the internet. Or uninstall ruby and reinstall it. I dont think anyone can post an answer for this.